# Mongoose update field if another array field has a size bigger than 5

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongoose and I cannot find a way to achieve a certain update query.
I have the next schema:

```
{
  usersJoined: [{
    type: String
  }],
  status: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
}
```

I want to update the status to 1 when the size of the usersJoined array is 5.
I am using the following query to query for the right document:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    status: 0,
    usersJoined: {$ne: user}
  },
  {
    $push: {usersJoined: user}
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you want to update the status when the total userJoined size is 5 (after new user is pushed)? So you are essentially looking for array with size 4?

Comment: Yes @TheeSritabtim. I want to push the user to the list anyways. Updating the status would only happen if the size reached 5

Answer (score 0):

> I want to update the status to 1 when the size of the usersJoined
>   array is 5

Use array [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/index.html) operator to filter records, findOneAndUpdate method will update the first matched record. Refer to document [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/). If this not suitable for your usecase check additional [update methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/update-methods/index.html)

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"userJoined": {"$size": 5}},
    {$set: {"status": 1}},
    {returnNewDocument: true} //if true, returns the updated document.
);
```

[Example](https://play.db-ai.co/m/XrFbGn7kZQABtB1r)

Comment: I want the object to be updated all the time, not only when the size is 5. When the size is 5, I also want the status to be set to 1

Comment: What do you want to be updated all the time? userJoined array? then you probably have to write 2 separate updates